# PHP: get gray level of a pixel (image)

Tags: php, image, grayscale

I want get the exact "gray level" of a given image in PHP. I can't understand why I always get `[0, 0, 0]` as RGB array using `imagecolorsforindex`. This is my code:

```
// load
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/white.jpeg");

// to grayscale
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

// just 1 pixel that describe the whole image
$grayLevel = resize_image($img, 1, 1);
$gray = imagecolorat($grayLevel, 1, 1);
$readble = imagecolorsforindex($grayLevel, $gray);

print_r($readble);
```

I first load my image (it's a completely white image, so every pixel should be [255, 255, 255] according to [this](https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/color-picker/)) and then transform it in grayscale. I resize the image to only one pixel that describe the entire image and I get the RGB array. The array is `[0, 0, 0]`.

I can't understand why I always get `[0, 0, 0]` with images in grayscale, with color. It the 1-pixel technique wrong?

Many thanks

PS: the `resize_image` works, I've tested it, anyway this is the code: https://pastebin.com/HNDzKq5E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pixel in the image exists at (0, 0), not (1, 1). Try changing

`$gray = imagecolorat($grayLevel, 1, 1);`

to

`$gray = imagecolorat($grayLevel, 0, 0);`

Comment: You are right! I was confused by the resizing call with 1,1. :)